# How does Apache Spark's CoarseGrainedScheduler get started?

Tags: java, apache-spark, appdynamics, apm

I'm trying to instrument a Spark (v 1.6.1) application with an APM (Application Performance Management System).  To do so with the APM of choice, I must instrument the JVM startup string(s) with a `-javaagent` flag, pointing to my APM along with any pertinent APM options (e.g., `unique-host-id`).

On the Spark Master server, I have done this successfully, and on the various Spark Worker servers, I have successfully instrumented the spark worker process as well.

However, when I look at the Java processes that are running, I see one additional process that does not contain my startup string: the CoarseGrainedScheduler.  The CoarseGrainedScheduler is the actual Spark executor which runs the worker application code submitted to the Worker by the Master.

**I cannot determine from where the CoarseGrainedScheduler is invoked.**

So, for more context, here's how I've instrumented the Spark Worker startup string: in `{SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark_env.sh`, I added the following environment variable:

`SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="<java-agent-startup-string>"`

This gets carried through to the eventual invocation of `{SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class`, which is the root of all Spark invocations; that is, all spark commands that emanate from `{SPARK_HOME}/bin` or `{SPARK_HOME}/sbin` eventually delegate to `spark_class`.

This is seemingly not, however, where CoarseGrainedScheduler is invoked from.  Looking at [this document](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-executor-backends-CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.adoc#run), though, that *is* where it gets invoked from:

```
$ ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend <opts>
```

Why, then, is my startup string not being picked up?  Working from the assumption/instruction that CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend is invoked via spark-class, I actually edited that file to add my startup string when running any java command, and that also fails to add my startup string to the CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend, although it does add it to the Spark Worker process itself.  So again, it seems as though CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend is not started via spark-class, even though the linked document says it is.

Can anyone help me find the root of the CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend process and how it's invoked?  If I can provide any additional details, just let me know.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?